# Shorten string without cutting words in flutter dart

Tags: dart

I want to get specific characters from the string but don't want to cut the last word.

Ex. get 28 characters from `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` and the result is like this **The quick brown fox jumps ov**

```
yourString.substring(0, maxLength);
```

here I don't want the last word if it got cut.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  var yourString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  int maxLength = 25; // maximum number of characters to extract

  if (yourString.length > maxLength) {
    //trim the string to the maximum length
    var trimmedString = yourString.substring(0, maxLength);

    print(trimmedString);

    //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
    var lastWord = trimmedString.split(' ').last;
    bool isFullWord = false;

    if (yourString.split(' ').any((item) => item == lastWord)) {
      isFullWord = true;
    }

    if (!isFullWord) {
      trimmedString = trimmedString.substring(
          0, math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));
    }

    print(trimmedString);
  }
}
```

[DartPad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=bc7d59ff2bad401db3dfdf22e443d7e0)

Comment: It cuts a word too many if it's already cut right. For example take maxLength 25. It should return "The quick brown fox jumps" but it removes "jumps" then as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be

```
  String yourString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  int maxLength = 28;

  if (yourString.length > maxLength) {
    int lastIndex = yourString.lastIndexOf(' ', maxLength);
    yourString = yourString.substring(0, lastIndex);
  }
  print(yourString); // The quick brown fox jumps
```

Using the `lastIndexOf` method, we can get the index of the last space before the maximum length if such is the case, The substring is then obtained using this index without the last word being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Work on this

```
String getTruncatedPhrase() {
  const int maxLength = 28;
  int currentLength = 0;
  const String yourString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  String result = yourString.split(" ").where((e) {
    currentLength += e.length;
    return currentLength < maxLength;
  }).join(" ");
  return result;
}
```

Comment: much better if 28 and string will pass as parameters into that function

Comment: "Work on this" meaning that @Nagual!!

Answer (score 0):

You want the resulted string at least or at most the specified length?

```
void main() {
  var yourString = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
  int maxLength = 28; // maximum number of characters to extract
  
  // resulting strings - smaller than length or with last word
  String smallerString = '';
  String biggerString = '';

  // split words, blank as separator
  var words = yourString.split(' ');

  var cnt = 0;
  while(biggerString.length < maxLength){
    smallerString = biggerString;
    // add spaces as word separation
    if (biggerString.isNotEmpty) {
      biggerString += ' ';
    }
    biggerString += words[cnt];
    cnt++;

    print('#$cnt: $biggerString / ${biggerString.length} - $smallerString / ${smallerString.length}');
  }
  print('\nThe longer is "$biggerString" and is ${biggerString.length} characters long');
  print('The shorter is "$smallerString" and is ${smallerString.length} characters long');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This function checks if the length of `longString` is less than or equal to `maxLength`. If so, it returns `longString` as is. If not, it shortens the string to `maxLength` characters and makes sure to cut it at the last occurrence of a space character, to avoid cutting off a word in the middle.

```dart
String shortenString(String longString, int maxLength) =>
    longString.length <= maxLength
        ? longString
        : longString
            .substring(0, maxLength)
            .substring(0, longString.substring(0, maxLength).lastIndexOf(' '));
```

Or you can use `regex` to achieve the same result:

```dart
String shortenString(String longString, int maxLength) =>
    longString.length <= maxLength
        ? longString
        : longString
            .replaceRange(maxLength, longString.length, '')
            .replaceAll(RegExp(r' \S*$'), '');
```